# DirectShow IsUsingTimeFormat vs. GetTimeFormat

Tags: directshow

I was reading through the documentation for the IMediaSeeking interface for DirectShow filters and noticed that there are two methods that appear to do the same thing, with slightly different semantics.

- [IsUsingTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407036(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [GetTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407034(v=vs.85).aspx)

The question is when should one be used vs. the other?

The documentation states that IsUsingTimeFormat is slightly more efficient because it doesn't require an extra mem copy operation but besides that, is there any other reason to prefer one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is on what you want to do.

`GetTimeFormat(...)` writes in a GUID structure that you pass the time format being used, if it succeeds in obtaining the timeformat it returns S_OK.

On the other hand, when using `IsUsingTimeFormat(...)` you are querying the filter if the GUID structure that you pass through its parameters is the one it is using.

So which one to use depends on what would you like to do, query the filter if it is using a specific GUID or trying to obtain the GUID of the time format from the filter.

Comment: I got that from the documentation but it seems suspicious to include two methods that accomplish almost the same thing in slightly different ways. Just curious if there's any hidden reason..

Answer (score 1):

The difference is [right there mentioned in the documetnation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407036):

> This method is slightly more efficient than the IMediaSeeking::GetTimeFormat method, because it does not require copying the GUID.

Keep in mind that this interface is about to celebrate its 20-th anniversary, and at that time a couple of unnecessary GUID copies made some difference... The interface has other methods duplicating one another, perhaps it was not the best design in first place and then it had to exist as designed to maintain compatibility.

Comment: It seems to be the case. MSDN seems really scarce in some areas that could benefit from additional background information. Especially for APIs that have been around for a couple decades..